"Error fetching access token" when deploying firebase project
I am following tutorial https://developers.home.google.com/codelabs/smarthome-washer?hl=en#7
But when performing the first firebase deploy command, I get 9 errors similar to this one :
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND"."}
At the end, I get message that deploy is completed. But when I go to next step of tutorial, and load URI https://.web.app, I get an empty page with just the upper banner.
Any idea of what is going wrong ?
I copy-paste here under the full log of deploy command.
Many thanks,
Brice

Brice@raspberrypi:~/smarthome-washer/washer-start $ firebase deploy

=== Deploying to 'maison-94615'...

i  deploying database, functions, hosting
i  database: checking rules syntax...
✔  database: rules syntax for database maison-94615-default-rtdb is valid
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
⚠  functions: package.json indicates an outdated version of firebase-functions. Please upgrade using npm install --save firebase-functions@latest in your functions directory.
⚠  functions: Please note that there will be breaking changes when you upgrade.
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8644

[2024-06-12T07:30:04.037Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}

[2024-06-12T07:30:04.884Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}

[2024-06-12T07:30:05.538Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}

[2024-06-12T07:30:06.478Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}

[2024-06-12T07:30:07.376Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}

[2024-06-12T07:30:09.135Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}

[2024-06-12T07:30:11.112Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: {"code":"app/invalid-credential","message":"Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the \"credential\" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: \"Error fetching access token: Error while making request: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND metadata.google.internal. Error code: ENOTFOUND\"."}

i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged /home/Brice/smarthome-washer/washer-start/functions (55.96 KB) for uploading
i  hosting[maison-94615]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[maison-94615]: found 3 files in public
✔  hosting[maison-94615]: file upload complete
i  database: releasing rules...
✔  database: rules for database maison-94615-default-rtdb released successfully
i  functions: Skipping the deploy of unchanged functions.
✔  functions[login(us-central1)] Skipped (No changes detected)
✔  functions[fakeauth(us-central1)] Skipped (No changes detected)
✔  functions[faketoken(us-central1)] Skipped (No changes detected)
✔  functions[smarthome(us-central1)] Skipped (No changes detected)
✔  functions[requestsync(us-central1)] Skipped (No changes detected)
✔  functions[reportstate(us-central1)] Skipped (No changes detected)
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
⚠  functions: Unhandled error cleaning up build images. This could result in a small monthly bill if not corrected. You can attempt to delete these images by redeploying or you can delete them manually at https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/maison-94615/us/gcf
i  hosting[maison-94615]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[maison-94615]: version finalized
i  hosting[maison-94615]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[maison-94615]: release complete

✔  Deploy complete!

Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/maison-94615/overview
Hosting URL: https://maison-94615.web.app



Based on the hosting URL mentioned in the log trace above, we suspect the project/cloud functions are not getting deployed properly. When we open the link https://maison-94615.web.app/, we see further errors in the console like "FIREBASE FATAL ERROR" .
As a reference you can go through the steps mentioned in the following codelab and try implementing your project again.
